# Orthogonal application and basis choice

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose we have an orthogonal linear application $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R^n}$. Let $\mathcal{B}_1, \mathcal{B}_2$ be two orthonormal basis and $A$ the matrix of $f$ with respect to ($\mathcal{B}_1, \mathcal{B}_2$). Is $A$ also an orthogonal matrix, this is $AA^T = I$?

I know the result is true if $\mathcal{B}_1 = \mathcal{B}_2$ and I would say is true for different basis also, since both are orthonormal, but I am not quite sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{B}_1=\{x_i\}$ and $\mathcal{B}_2=\{y_i\}$ and write $f(x_i)=\sum_j a_{ji}y_j$. Then

$$\delta_{ij}=\langle x_i,x_j\rangle=\langle f(x_i),f(x_j)\rangle=\langle\sum_ka_{ki}y_k,\sum_{\ell}a_{\ell j}y_{\ell}\rangle=\sum_k a_{ki}a_{kj}.$$
Hence $AA^{\intercal}=I$ where $A$ is the matrix of $f$ with respect to the bases $\mathcal{B}_1$ and $\mathcal{B}_2$.